# how to use subquery for this type of case

Tags: subquery

**Getting Subquery returns more than 1 row but i want to get visit count by multiple dates**

```
SELECT COUNT('visit') as total_visit1,employee_id, 
    (SELECT COUNT('visit') as total_visit2 from employee_meeting
        WHERE visit_date between '2018-07-29' and '2018-09-29 23:59:59.999' and employee_id='123') as total_new FROM employee_meeting WHERE visit_date between '2018-07-29' and '2018-09-29 23:59:59.999' and employee_id='123'
```

Comment: kindly format your query. Do you want get the result as datewise group count. demo your desired output also

Comment: what result you are getting now

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT `employee_id`,date_format(`visit_date`,'%d-%M-%Y') dt,count(*) FROM `employee_meeting` group by `employee_id`,date_format(`visit_date`,'%d-%M-%Y')
```

Comment: its working but getting wrong data because i want to visit count as per multiple dates.

Comment: question is not clear. edit your question and show current table with sample data and show expected table output